# WPF Restrict ContentControl to interface

Tags: wpf, contentcontrol

I'm using WPF and C#.

I want a ContentControl to accept only controls as content that implement a certain interface. Can anyone help me on how to to this? The reason is to ensure, that only the right controltypes can be used.

thanks.

**Edit:**
In addition to the question:
Maybe somthing like

```
[ValidType(typeof(MyInterface))]
public class MyContentControl : ContentControl
{
...
}
```

I also thought about a generic form like

```
public class MyContentControl<T> : ContentControl
 where T : MyInterface
{}
```

Unfortunately, that way I would have to create a ContentControl for each type that could happen to be hosted.

Just a thought, but is it possible the create a MarkupExtension for that purpose? If so, can someone help me here, please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing source code enables members to offer more specific advice. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly should happen when an "unacceptable" object is placed as content? An exception? A message in the Output Window?

Comment: Ideally, a debug error in the errorlist. But I do understand, that injection is happening on runtime, so at least an error should be thrown. A message in the output window would be helpfull as well. I think Debugger.Log should take care of that part properly.